# Understanding this Dynkin system $\pi-\lambda$ proof that a CDF completely determines a distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions

I read that the CDF of a random variable completely determines its distribution, that is, knowing $F(y) = P(Y \leq y)$ for all $y \in \mathbb{R}$ determines $P(Y\in B)$ for all Borel sets $B \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. The proof outline I read was as follows:

Suppose the probability space triple we work with is: $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}, P)$. If two CDFs $F_X$ and $F_Y$ are equal, i.e., $P_X = P_Y$ on the set $S = \{(-\infty, a]: a\in \mathbb{R}\}$, which is a $\pi$-system; then it can be shown from a corollary to the $\pi-\lambda$ theorem that $P_X = P_Y$ on $\sigma(S)$. But, $\sigma(S) = \mathcal{B}$, so knowing $P_X$ on $S$ determines $P_X$ on $\mathcal{B}$.

Here, everything makes sense except for the part where they work with two CDFs. I don't know why they introduced two CDFs. Is it to link the $P_X$ via the $P_Y$? It seems that if we have two CDFs, it adds ambiguity. Am I missing something here?